# Javax.sound not avaiable in android

Tags: java, android, audio-recording, android-mediarecorder, javax.sound.sampled

I am trying to use javax.sound package in android. But android stopped this javax support. I have tried to port my javax.sound dependent code to android also but its not working. The key point is I need the sound raw data from AudioInputStream like the javax.sound package do.

I m lost somewhere I don't know. If anybody knows about the alternative of javax.sound package please reply.

Comment: You are going need to be more specific in your problem. What are you doing with `javax.sound.*`? What does the original code look like? What progress have you made in porting it?

Comment: I am also looking for the same, for call recording purpose, but not found. Currently, I am using a media recorder for call recording but it does not record both side audio properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to read the data from the devices, there is a class called [android.media.AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) which will help you read raw data. If you need to decode some files, and you are using Android 4.1+, then you can also use the class [android.media.MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html), which provides the necessary low-level interface to audio codecs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, In my knowledge of java I thing `javax` is a package that supports `swings` that is a toolkit used for `UI` and `Multimedia operations`.

But this is not supported in `android-sdk` as you have a number of options to achieve the same and have a good responsive and needed callbacks via sdk provided methods.

So I will recommend you to go for `MediaPlayer` API provided by android that would suffice in your case.

Comment: Javax is a lot more than just swing and Android supports/includes some  javax packages.  API 26 includes javax.crypto, javax.net, javax.xml and more.  See https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/package-summary for example.